# How to have two divs next to each other and still have a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have 2 divs inside one content div be side by side (Left & Right, see example below) while still have a different die for a sidebar. I've tried using floats but that doesn't align the right div at the correct height. I've also tried using the new CSS grid layout method but nothing changes when I add it to my code so I deleted it.

```css
.main-content {
  border-style: solid;
  color: #DC143C;
  width: 75%;
}

.main-content-left-side {   
  color: #DC143C;
}

.main-content-right-side {
  color: #DC143C;
  height: 300px;
}

.sidecontent {
  width: 300;
  color: #DC143C;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left: 100px;  
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2.previousvid {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px; 
}

p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #DC143C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DC143C;
}

ol {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<header> 
  <ul class="left";> 
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top leftbuttons";          
    href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top leftbuttons";           
    href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="logobutton";   
    href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmZOe6sv3wuq97Vo-9Rdyyw";  
    target="_blank";>RG</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top rightbuttons";    
    href="#">Archives</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top rightbuttons"; 
    href="#">Suggestions</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="main-content">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Hello welcome to my site you guys know me already Recht A.K.A Domo.                                                        Here you can find my video upload schedule, previous video, current video, and you can make suggestions on what games I play.</p>
  <hr>
  <div class="main-content-left-side";>
    <h2>Previous Video (As of Jun-29-16):</h2>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bDXMLKNPUGw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content-right-side"> 
    <ol>
      <li id="schedule";>Mondays: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Tuesday: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Wendsday: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Thurday: Break</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Friday: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Saturday: Production</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Sunday: Production</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I want it to be:

[image]

Comment: make the two divs `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flex`. Keep left and right divs in a `div` with `dispaly:flex` and remove `padding-left` to `ol`

```css
.main-content {
  border-style: solid;
  color: #DC143C;
  width: 75%;
}

.main-content-left-side {   
  color: #DC143C;
}

.main-content-right-side {
  color: #DC143C;
  height: 300px;
}

.sidecontent {
  width: 300;
  color: #DC143C;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left: 100px;  
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2.previousvid {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px; 
}

p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
}

hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #DC143C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DC143C;
}

ol {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header> 
  <ul class="left";> 
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top leftbuttons";          
    href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top leftbuttons";           
    href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="logobutton";   
    href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmZOe6sv3wuq97Vo-9Rdyyw";  
    target="_blank";>RG</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top rightbuttons";    
    href="#">Archives</a></li>
    <li class="nav";><a class="a a-nav-top rightbuttons"; 
    href="#">Suggestions</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="main-content">
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Hello welcome to my site you guys know me already Recht A.K.A Domo.                                                        Here you can find my video upload schedule, previous video, current video, and you can make suggestions on what games I play.</p>
  <hr>
  <div class="main-container">
  <div class="main-content-left-side";>
    <h2>Previous Video (As of Jun-29-16):</h2>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bDXMLKNPUGw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content-right-side"> 
    <ol>
      <li id="schedule";>Mondays: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Tuesday: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Wendsday: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Thurday: Break</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Friday: Upload</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Saturday: Production</li>
      <li id="schedule";>Sunday: Production</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```